# Incorrect Array Length

Tags: javascript

`console.log(data)` reveals the foll​owing:

```
(4) […]
​
0: "a19870e84cc92abeb5904fccd1f74329"
​
1: "12793d4229b32a0b1fc387e041ed7be8"
​
2: "12793d4229b32a0b1fc387e041ed7be8"
​
3: "5fec6cd9e7c78a4a985d1f5b82f05280"
​
length: 4
```

Yet, `console.log(data.length)` says the following:

```
0
```

..and indeed, I'm unable to loop through the array with a `for` loop because `data.length = 0`.

How can my array have 4 elements but have zero length all at once? I'm confused.

ps. the array gets produced via an async' redux function, here:

```
export const getFiles = () => {
  return async (dispatch: AppDispatch, getState: Function) => {

    const state = getState()
    const scriptAddress = state.chainInfo.data.scriptAddress

    var fileData: string[] = []

    api.cmd("coins;", function(respJSON: any) {

      if( api.util.checkAllResponses(respJSON) ) {

        //console.log(respJSON)
        const coins = respJSON[0].response.coins
        for ( let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++ ) {
          if (coins[i].data.coin.address == scriptAddress) {
            fileData.push(coins[i].data.prevstate[0].data)
          }
        }
      }
    })
  
    dispatch(write({data: fileData})(GetActionTypes.GET_SUCCESS))
  }
}
```

And it updates a react component via `mapStateToProps` - so it only gets the data after the async operation has updated the store via a `reducer`. So I don't 'think' it's an `async` problem.

And gosh - I should've mentioned all the react, redux, mapState stuff. Sorry!

Comment: Can you replicate this in a snippet here? It would be nice to see more of the code

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Possibly related: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: @TasosBu - not easy to reproduce as the code's spread out amongst redux store stuff...

Comment: @Jamiec - unfortunately, I can't do that very easily...

Comment: Just create a snippet and paste the contents of the data in it and print its length

Comment: @DBS - I'm experiencing the 'zero' behaviour in code, too (i.e. I'm unable to loop through the array). So I don't think it's a console thing...

Comment: Im guessing that the value of data changes after the console.log(data)

Comment: Asynchronous could be tricky, probably you are trying to make some operations before promise is resolved. More code will help with the investigation

Comment: Okay - I've added a copy of the code producing the array...

Comment: Dispatch i called to early, I guess that api.cmd is asynchronous (with callback) but you are not waiting till results will be processed. Please move `dispatch` after for loop.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski dispatch IS called after the for loop and AFTER api.cmd has returned.

Comment: @glowkeeper mayby `await` is missing in above example. Current code tries to handle asynchronous in not proper way.

Comment: api.cmd is a promise - no need for await, so async' code is 'probably' correct.

Comment: But actually, @KrzysztofSafjanowski - you gave me an idea - and it's fixed!

Answer (score 1):

`length` is just an property, you are able to overwrite by mistake for example:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log('before: ', a.length)
a.length = 0;
console.log('after: ', a.length)
```

Comment: Yes - and I'm accessing that property above - you'll see it says '4' when I log the data, but '0' when I log data.length. I promise you I am not overwriting it in between calls (at least, not intentionally).

Comment: Can you verify that .length works as expected by running `console.log([1].length)` ?

Comment: Also try and print data and data.length in the same console.log like this: `console.log(data, "length: ", data.length)`

Comment: @TasosBu - I do that (`console.log(data, data.length)` - I just simplified for the example. It produces this: Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ] 0

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!

I moved the dispatch *inside* `api.cmd`, and `data.length` behaves correctly:

```
export const getFiles = () => {
  return async (dispatch: AppDispatch, getState: Function) => {

    const state = getState()
    const scriptAddress = state.chainInfo.data.scriptAddress

    var fileData: string[] = []

    api.cmd("coins;", function(respJSON: any) {

      if( api.util.checkAllResponses(respJSON) ) {

        //console.log(respJSON)
        const coins = respJSON[0].response.coins
        for ( let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++ ) {
          if (coins[i].data.coin.address == scriptAddress) {
            fileData.push(coins[i].data.prevstate[0].data)
          }
        }
      }
  
      dispatch(write({data: fileData})(GetActionTypes.GET_SUCCESS))
    })
  }
}
```

**Boom!** Thanks for all the comments...

Comment: Glad you solved your problem - we never really had a chance of helping you with the information you originally provided. Next time include the code causing the problem and we'll be more successful :)